# Fair coin probability of Heads

Tags: probability

I have a fair coin which I toss many times. What is the probability that it takes 12 rolls until I get two heads in a row?

I thought this was just standard geometric. But it doesn’t seem to work? Can someone please explain how to do this? As well in maybe a more general way? Thank you

Comment: Takes exactly 12 rolls or at least 12 rolls? And in the first case you mean then that roll 11 gives a head and roll 12 gives also a head, and this is the first time you get two heads in a row?

Comment: Learn Markov chains.

Answer (score 2):

Call a sequence admissible if it doesn't contain two consecutive heads.  Then we must have an admissible sequence of length $9$, followed by the sequence THH.  Let $a_n$ be the number of admissible sequence of length $n$, $t_n$ be the number of such sequences that end in T, and let $h_n$ be the number of such sequences ending in H.

Clearly, $$a_n=t_n+h_n.$$  Also, $$h_n=t_{n-1},$$ since the last H is an admissible sequence ending in H must be preceded by an admissible sequence ending in T.  However, there is no such restriction on an admissible sequence ending in T, so $$t_n=t_{n-1}+h_{n-1}=t_{n-1}+t_{n-2},$$ and we see the Fibonacci numbers, as noted by @DonThousand.

Note that $$a_9=t_9+h_9=t_9+t_8=t_{10}=89.$$

Answer (score 0):

So, the first ten flips have no consecutive heads, which means that we can look at the different flips sequences by filling in the $10$ flips with either $T$ or $HT$. It's well known that there are $F_{10}=89$ ($F$ is the fibonacci sequence) ways for this to happen.

So, the answer is $$89\cdot2^{-12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution, done longer, but in the spirit of probability theory. (It may generalize easier if we slightly change $HH$ to some other string, but computations would become harder to manage.)

---

We consider a Markov chain with three states denoted by $*$, $*H$, $*HH$, where $*$ is any word in the alphabet with two letters $T,H$ which is not ending in $H$. The start is the empty word, so it belongs to the box $*$, and we make $*HH$ absorbant, once in there, we no longer get out of it. Else we pass from each word $w$ (not ending in $HH$) with probability $1/2$  to $wT$, and with the other $1/2$ to $wH$. The transition matrix for this chain is
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The initial distribution is $q=[1\ 0\ 0]$. (We entry the state $*$ by starting with the empty word.) Then the distribution of probabilities for the states after $n$ steps is $qA^n$. On can explicitly compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
qA^{11} &= \left[\
\frac{9}{128}     \frac{89}{2048} \frac{1815}{2048}
\right]\ ,
\\
qA^{12} &= \left[\ 
\frac{233}{4096}     \frac9{256} \frac{3719}{4096}
\right]\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so the third entry computes the probability to reach the absorbant state in at most $11$, respectively $12$ steps, so the searched probability is the difference $\displaystyle \frac{3719}{4096}-\frac{1815}{2048}=\frac{89}{4096}$.

The above is a too complicated way to extract that third entry in $qA^{12}-qA^{11}$, so let us compute simpler. First of all, we can ignore the cases when the state $*HH$ is reached earlier, so we can ignore the third row and column, and ask which is the probability to land in $*H$ after exactly $11$ steps. (Without touching $*HH$.) So we consider instead the start $r=[1\ 0]$ and the passage matrix
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac 12
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,
$$
and compute $rB^{11}$. We can diagonalize or recognize directly the pattern:
$$
B=\frac 12
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
B^2 = \frac 1{2^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
B^3 = \frac 1{2^3}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\ 
B^4 = \frac 1{2^4}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3 \\
3 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\\
B^5 = \frac 1{2^5}
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 5 \\
5 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\ \dots\ , \ 
B^{11} = \frac 1{2^{11}}
\begin{bmatrix}
144 & 89 \\
89 & 55 
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\ \dots
$$
and so on, and the entries in the powers of $B$ are "rolling Fibonacci numbers". After $11$ steps we are with probabilities $rB^{11}=\frac 1{2^{11}}[\ 144\ 89\ ]$ in $*$, respectively $*H$, (the remained probability corresponds to the absorbant $*HH$,) so we land exactly the step $12$ in $*HH$ with probability 
$$
\frac {89}{2^{11}}\cdot \frac 12\ .
$$
The Fibonacci numbers come from the characteristic polynomial of the matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.